# Android EditText not writing from left to right

Tags: android, android-edittext, onchange, seekbar

I've got a `EditText` which changes a `Seekbar` if the `Text` is being edited but it writes from right to left for some reason.

This is the way I do it

```
priceText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable mEdit) {
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            priceSeekbar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(priceText.getText().toString()));
        }
    });
```

XML

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/priceAmount"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_height="22dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_edittext"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
        />
```

I think it's caused by

```
priceSeekbar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(priceText.getText().toString()));
```

When I remove this line, it goes back to normal but I'm not sure why. Any ideas?

Comment: at first `android:textSize="15sp"`

Comment: Where is `priceSeekbar` is relation to your EditText, since you say it influences your text direction like that. You can also try `priceSeekbar.setProgress` in `afterTextChanged` instead, might be the updating that focuses/unfocuses.

Comment: Using 'afterTextChanged' doesn't work. Problem is that after I give a input, it puts the cursor on the left side of the text. I'm not sure what you mean with the relation between 'priceSeekbar' end 'EditText'. What I'm ttrying to do is to change the progress of the 'Seekbar' when the 'Text' is being changed. This does happen now, but writing from |right to left is still a problem.

Comment: @JasonLie by relation I was referring to where they are on the layout. Although it's unlikely, they might be re-laid out which will reset the cursor position. It also occurs to me that setting the progress might also be focusing the seekbar.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this

```
<EditText
     ...
     android:gravity="left"
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `android:gravity="left"`

Comment: this only puts the text on the left side but it still writes from right to left. Problem is that after I give a input, it puts the cursor on the left side of the text.

Comment: I see, in that case use this to move the cursor to the end after adding the input: `priceText.setSelection(priceText.getText().length());`